# Find $f: \mathbb R\times [0,\infty)\to \mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ bijective , continuous, not homemorphic .

Tags: general-topology

Find f, bijective, continuous non homeomorphic function from the upper closed semi plane to $R^2$ minus 0. I have tried:

1. $(x,\ln(y))$ but does not work in $y=0$ and have issues with $(0,0)=f(0,1)$
2. $re^{i\theta}$, $r\in (0,\infty),\theta\in(\pi,2\pi)$, but this function doesn’t have $\{(x,y): y>=0\}$ in its codomain.

It is an example of a bijective non homeomorphic function read in a topology pdf, it was left for the reader to solve, just curious.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Tried (x,ln(y)), but doesn’t work on y=0 and sends (0,1) to (0,0).

Comment: Try to map continuously every line of the type $\mathbb{R} \times \lbrace y \rbrace$ onto a line of the type $\lbrace r e^{i \theta}, r > 0 \rbrace$.

Comment: I have tried, but I do not know how transform the x axis onto itself, if identity is used on the x axis, the function is not continuous under any topology I know. It is a bijection though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Consider for example

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
f & : & \mathbb{R} \times [0,+\infty) & \to & \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \lbrace (0,0) \rbrace \simeq \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \\
 & & (x,y) & \mapsto & e^{x+4i \arctan(y)}  \\
\end{array}$$